# Model dependency target which link at runtime

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Say I got two CMake targets, `myexe` and `mylib`, where `mylib` is `SHARED`.

I'm loading `mylib` from `myexe` at runtime (using `dlopen`). So my requirement is that when I build `myexe`, `mylib` will also get built. To my understanding, `target_link_libraries()` is not accurate here because linkage is at runtime only.

How can I model that in CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simple `add_dependencies` for make one target to automatically build another one:

```
# The library used via dlopen should be built with MODULE type.
add_library(mylib MODULE <mylib-source-files>)

add_executable(myexe <myexe-source-files>)
# For build myexe, mylib should also be built.
add_dependencies(myexe mylib)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did mention dlopen so I assume you are running your code on Linux where you don't need to export the dll functions with __declspec (dllexport) and don't need the static export library.

So I think you are doing things right using target_link_libraries.

As you can see in this [link](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/creating-using-shared-libraries-different-compilers-different-operating-systems/), à complete cmakelists.txt file covering windows and Linux would be:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(sharedLibsDemo)                 # create a project with the given name
add_library(shared SHARED shared.cpp)   # compile "shared.cpp" and create a SHARED library called "shared"
add_executable(main main.cpp)           # compile "main.cpp" the the executable called "main"
include (GenerateExportHeader)          
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(shared           # generates the export header shared_EXPORTS.h automatically
    BASE_NAME shared
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME shared_EXPORTS
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME shared_EXPORTS.h
    STATIC_DEFINE SHARED_EXPORTS_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
target_link_libraries(main shared)
```

So, this is true for direct dynamic linking. On Linux, you can check your executable dependencies using ldd to make sure your program is referencing the library.

However if you use dlopen(), then you are already specifying the dll path and loading it dynamically. This means, you don't need to use target_link_libraries() when you build your program.

In both cases, direct link or dlopen(), you may need to update LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable.

Comment: My takeout is same as yours - I don't need `target_link_libraries()`. But that's my question - I still want to force the build of `shared` when I build `main`.

Comment: @galah92  addLibrary should be enough then as long as the library is part of the same cmake project

Comment: But it isn't. `make main` won't build `shared`.